# Remote directory doesn't exit error when uploading

Tags: python, django, paramiko

`exceptions.IOError` when i run `python mysftpclient.py` . I am new to python, Can you tell what causing this error...?

**Error**

```
*** Caught exception: <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 2] Directory does not exist.
============================================================
Total files copied: 0
All operations complete!
============================================================
```

**Code**

```
def put_dir(self, source, target):
    ''' Uploads the contents of the source directory to the target path. The
        target directory needs to exists. All subdirectories in source are 
        created under target.
    '''
    for item in os.listdir(source):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, item)):
            self.put(os.path.join(source, item), '%s/%s' % (target, item))
        else:
            my_mkdir(self, '%s/%s' % (target, item), 551, ignore_existing=True)
            put_dir(self, os.path.join(source, item), '%s/%s' % (target, item))

def my_mkdir(self, sftp, path, mode=511, ignore_existing=False):
    ''' Augments mkdir by adding an option to not fail if the folder exists  '''
    try:
        sftp.mkdir(path, mode)
    except IOError:
        if ignore_existing:
            pass
        else:
            raise
```

Update

I think below the line causing the issue

```
# now, connect and use paramiko Transport to negotiate SSH2 across the connection
try:
    print 'Establishing SSH connection to:', hostname, port, '...'
    t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    t.connect()

    agent_auth(t, username)

    if not t.is_authenticated():
        print 'RSA key auth failed! Trying password login...'
        t.connect(username=username, password=password, hostkey=hostkey)
    else:
        sftp = t.open_session()
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
    parent=os.path.split(dir_local)[1]
    try:
        sftp.mkdir(parent)
        sftp.chdir(parent)
    except IOError, e:
        print '(assuming ', dir_remote, 'exists)', e
    put_dir(sftp, dir_local, dir_remote)
except Exception, e:
    print '*** Caught exception: %s: %s' % (e.__class__, e)
    try:
        t.close()
    except:
        pass
print '=' * 60
print 'Total files copied:',files_copied
print 'All operations complete!'
print '=' * 60
```

I don't know somehow i am getting

```
(assuming  /NewFolder/201410181636099007 exists) Unable to create the file/directory
```

Comment: have you tried the answer provided by me ? what's result you got ?

Answer (score 0):

I think "sftp.mkdir(parent)" is throwing this exception. And then it directly jumps to exception block where it is printing error which you are mentioning.

```
(assuming  /NewFolder/201410181636099007 exists) Unable to create the file/directory
```

then your script is calling put_dir which might be expecting path set into paramiki SFTP by sftp.chdir(parent) but which is not true when exception is raised.

I think you can put "sftp.chdir(parent)" line just before put_dir as in any case you would like to set your path. 
For example,

```
 try:
        sftp.mkdir(parent)
 except IOError, e:
        print '(assuming ', dir_remote, 'exists)', e

    sftp.chdir(parent)
    put_dir(sftp, dir_local, dir_remote)
```